# What tax benefits do people gain from donating to 501(c)(3)s?

Tags: united-states, taxes, donation, charity

Isn't the tax system progressive, so that your first (rough numbers from memory most likely inaccurate) say, $12000 gets taxed at X%, while your next, say, $8000 gets taxed at Y% (Y>X), and your next $50000 gets taxed at Z% (Z>Y).

In this case, supposing you had earned $22,000 in a year and then donated $2000 to a charity in the hopes of saving on taxes and taking home more, it doesn't actually have any effect on the rate at which your remaining $20,000 is taxed at, whether you donate or retain the additional $2000, right? So if you donate it then you are paying Y% tax on $20,000, and then forfeiting to the charity 100% of the donated $2000. Where are the savings when you could otherwise keep (100-Y)% of $20,000 (as before), on top of (100-Z)% of $2000?

I remember last year Mark Benioff donated $30mm to study the causes of homelessness, and everyone was marveling at how insane that is until someone weighed in that it was done to benefit his tax rate. But how does it do this?

Tl;dr: when rich people make contributions to tax-deductible charities to benefit themselves in the tax code, how does it actually benefit them? (Not referring to the metaphysical feelings of warmth & fuzziness.)

Comment: When the money/asset inside the 501(c)(3) is eventually funneled back to the donor.

Comment: For normal people, there is no way to obtain a financial benefit from making a charitable contribution.  Though the tax code is so complicated I wouldn't be shocked that a rich person figures out a way...

Comment: People frequently misunderstand how deductions work, so good question. You can let the person that "weighed in that it was done to benefit his tax rate" know that the tax benefit is dwarfed by the millions given away.

Answer (score 3):

There is no net gain.
I am in the 22% bracket and when I donate $1000 to charity, I see my net tax bill drop $220.

When I ‘donate’ to someone in need directly, there’s no such deduction. Which is why it’s better from a tax perspective to use a registered charity.

Similar to how I look at mortgage interest - the tax deduction can be a discount on the mortgage rate but not a reason to get a mortgage - donations should be made because you are so inclined or because your religion commands you to do so, but not “for the tax deduction”

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't the tax system progressive, so that your first (rough numbers from memory most likely inaccurate) say, $12000 gets taxed at X%, while your next, say, $8000 gets taxed at Y% (Y>X), and your next $50000 gets taxed at Z% (Z>Y).

The term for this is "marginal tax rates".

> In this case, supposing you had earned $22,000 in a year and then donated $2000 to a charity in the hopes of saving on taxes and taking home more, it doesn't actually have any effect on the rate at which your remaining $20,000 is taxed at, whether you donate or retain the additional $2000, right?

Wrong.

That is because all deductions (including charitable ones) reduce your Adjusted Gross Income, which is calculated **next year during tax season** after you've earned all your money.

IOW, no matter when in the year you contribute that $2000, for tax purposes it's taken "off the top".

(However, the person contributing $2000 to charity won't get any tax benefits because you only get a benefit if you **itemize deductions** on your tax return **instead of** using the Standard Deduction.  But the Standard Deduction is $12,400 for Singles.)

> when rich people make contributions to tax-deductible charities to benefit themselves in the tax code, how does it actually benefit them?

See above.

Comment: I'm not sure your "Wrong." and the bit following makes sense. Ignoring the itemizing issue at the end, if someone earned $22,000 and had $2,000 of charitable giving then what OP stated is correct, the charitable contribution has no bearing on the rate at which the remaining $20,000 is taxed at.

Comment: @HartCO the question seems pretty confused.  I interpret it as asking whether that $2K is pulled "off the bottom" of his income (which gets paid at X%) vs what really happens: it's taken "off the top" (the Z%).  I might be interpreting it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have the the concept correct. If you donate $X to a charity it will save you Y% of your donation in taxes. Donating money, or stuff, to a charity never saves as much as the value of the item.

There could be a few very rare edge cases where donating money or stuff gets you under a threshold, but since the the tax deduction takes place late in the tax calculation process it doesn't apply to very many people.

I view the ability to deduct a charitable contribution as a bonus. It makes it easier to afford the contribution. When the tax changes were made in late 2017, it moved me from somebody who itemizes to somebody who takes the standard deduction. I could have upped my charitable deduction significantly to get back to being a itemizer, but it would have taken thousands of dollars to get back over the threshold, and would have returned very little monetary benefit.

I predicted that donations to some charities would drop after the tax changes. They did. It will be interesting to see what happens to charities in 2020/2021 because of the crisis.